# リストの取り出す値の条件を別のリストにする方法

Tags: python3, pandas, csv

```
A = [1,1,1,.....-1,-1,1]
B =     apple,   banana
    0     333,      356
    1     364,      675
    2     643,      346
　　.     ...,      ...
   344    325,      356
```

Bはcsvをdataframe型で読み込んでいます．
AとBは同じ345個です．
このとき，Aが１のとき，Bのappleの値だけを抽出したいです．
B.iloc[np.where(A>0)]とすると，apple,banana両方が抽出されるため，
B.iloc[np.where(A>0),0]としましたが，インデックスが多いとエラーがでました．

できるだけ，forで取り出さないやり方はありますでしょうか．

Comment: `B.iloc[np.where(A>0)]['apple']` とすればよろしいかと思います。

Answer (score 0):

```
B.loc[A > 0, 'apple']
```

でよいのでは